# Python factory_boy library m2m in Django model?

Tags: python, django, testing, factory, fixtures

I'm currently using `factory_boy` for creating fixtures in my tests. 
`Factory_boy` docs only mentioned about `SubFactory` which could act like a `ForeignKey` field in a model. However, there was nothing on ManyToMany association. If I had a following Post model, how would I go about creating a factory for it?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('tags.Tag')

class PostFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Post

    title = 'My title'
    tags = ???
```

Comment: Hey @Ngo did you get an answer that worked?

Comment: @Daryl: overriding _prepare seems to be the easiest solution :)

Answer (score 11):

What about [post_generation hook](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/post_generation.html#postgeneration-and-post-generation) - I assume You use newer version of [factory_boy](https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy)?

```
import random
import factory

class PostFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Post
    title = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "This is test title number" + n)
    @factory.post_generation(extract_prefix='tags')
    def add_tags(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        # allow something like PostFactory(tags = Tag.objects.filter())
        if extracted and type(extracted) == type(Tag.objects.all()):
            self.tags = extracted
            self.save()
        else:
            if Tag.objects.all().count() < 5:
                TagFactory.create_batch(5, **kwargs)
            for tag in Tag.objects.all().order_by('?')[:random.randint(1, 5)]:
                self.tags.add(tag)
```

Note that You can use `PostFactory(tags__field = 'some fancy default text')`, but I recommend to create good `TagFactory` with Sequences ...

You should be able to bind `PostFactory(tags = Tag.objects.filter())` but this part is not tested ...

Answer (score 7):

You can override the `_prepare` classmethod:

```
class PostFactory(Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Post

    title = 'My title'

    @classmethod
    def _prepare(cls, create, **kwargs):
        post = super(PostFactory, cls)._prepare(create, **kwargs)
        if post.id:
            post.tags = Tag.objects.all()
        return post
```

Note that you can't add tags to a post if the post doesn't have an ID.

Answer (score 2):

I did not test it, but what is the problem with:

```
class PostFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Post
    title = 'My title'

class TagFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Tag

post = PostFactory()
tag = TagFactory()
post.tags.add(tag)
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. But I'd like to do this: post = PostFactory() and there will be let's say 4 tags added automatically without having to manually specify post.tags.add(tag)

Comment: I don't think factory_boy allows that. But why don't you just create a function that does that for you?
def PostFactoryWithFourTags():
    post = PostFactory()
    for _ in xrange(4):
        post.tags.add(TagFactory()
    return post