# Testing. How to add to database many objects with foreign key (automatically)?

Tags: python, django, testing

How to add to database many objects with foreign key (automatically)?

I need this for test (How the application works with multiple data)

```
class Document(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    add_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I need to create ten sample users (`User`) and each of them must have fifty documents (`Document`)

Comment: And you can't use [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/)?

Comment: How? I don't have a JSON file with data

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for [`FactoryBoy`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#defining-factories) where you can use [`SubFactories`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#associations) for easily creating associated objects.

Also the [`post_generation`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/post_generation.html#postgenerationhook) hook [demonstrated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365334/630877) should be handy.

Answer (score 2):

```
I need to create ten sample users (User) and each of them must have fifty documents (Document)
```

Try to use [Mixer](https://github.com/klen/mixer)

```
from mixer.backend.django import mixer

users = mixer.cycle(10).blend(User)
documents = mixer.cycle(50).blend(Document, user=mixer.sequence(*users))
```

Answer (score 1):

use inline-formset function, you can add as many as you can

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import sample
from string import ascii_letters
from datetime import datetime
for i in range(10):
    user = User.objects.create_user(''.join(sample(asci_letters, 5)),
                                    'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
    for j in range(50):
        doc = Document.objects.create(
            user=user, 
            content=''.join(sample(asci_letters, 100)), 
            add_time=datetime.datetime.now())
        doc.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. How to protect a database from errors: SQLite Exception: SQLite Busy ?

Comment: A quick fix might be to add time.sleep(0.1) in the document create loop - but that's really not a good thing to be doing :-D